# Why were the Titan II's Flames Clear?

Tags: launch, rockets, fuel, liquid-fuel, exhaust

I've seen multiple sources attribute the clear flames to the use of hypergolic fuels for propulsion, but I have been unable to find any explanation for why hypergolic fuels burn clearly.

[image]

<sub>(Image Source: [Spaceflight Now](https://spaceflightnow.com/titan/g9/031014titan2.html))</sub>

Comment: I was wondering if you actually mean "why not the red-brown we associate with Nitrogen Tetroxide", for which the point is that colour is the colour of room temperature non-combusting vapour, of which I think a fair bit is dissociating into N02. Anyway, after a bit of thought I suspect you are there already.This article is interesting in that it provides a few more photos http://www.clavius.org/techengine.html. By the way, I haven't posted this as an answer as, sticking to your question as to "why" exactly, I know no more than you.

Comment: @Puffin: Nitrogen dioxide _is_ the red-brown we associate with "nitrogen tetroxide" (which, in fact, is almost entirely dissociated into nitrogen dioxide at greater-than-cryogenic temperatures); dinitrogen tetroxide itself is colourless.

Answer (score 6):

Flame color should not be directly related to hypergolic...ity(?). Rather, it's dependent on the chemical properties of the particular fuel and oxidizer, and their products.

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGM-25C_Titan_II#Development):

> The Titan II also used storable propellants: [Aerozine 50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerozine_50), which is a 1:1 mixture of [hydrazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrazine) and [unsymmetrical dimethylhydrazine (UDMH)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsymmetrical_dimethylhydrazine), and [dinitrogen tetroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinitrogen_tetroxide).

As to why those chemicals burn with a colorless flame, I can tell you that it has to do with electron configurations and excitation states, but for any more detail, you might want to ask on the chemistry site.

Comment: This answer boils down to 'because they are'.....

Comment: The lack of color is a bit surprising, since I'd expect some of the carbon in UDMH to form soot, which tends to provide a red-yellow glow when heated.

Answer (score 3):

I read in the book [Ignition](https://archive.org/details/ignition_201612/page/n119) by John D. Clark about the liquid rocket fuel history in a footnote on page 105 that the Titan II flame is distinct in being nearly invisible because of the N2O4 and 50:50 propellants.  The author writes that the LOX RP-1 mix has free carbon which produces a luminous flame.

Elsewhere in the book is mentioned that a stated goal of the propellant designer is to avoid carbon in the exhaust as it provides little to no thrust being a solid so it may be that all the carbon in the hypergolic mix is burnt to CO and becomes a colourless gas while providing thrust.

The Titan I used LOX and RP-1 so would have shown a bright orange exhaust.

There is a picture of a Titan with carbon containing exhaust plumes down on a [Popular Science](https://www.popsci.com/how-nasa-chose-an-untested-missile-to-launch-gemini#page-4) page but this may be a Titan I even though it is captioned a Titan II or it may have been retouched to add colour where there was none (for artistic reasons).  Compare with the image in this question and on the [Titan II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGM-25C_Titan_II) wikipedia page.

Comment: The first picture of a Titan with a bright yellow exhaust flame on that Popsci page is a Titan I (and so captioned) -- the upper stage necks down the body diameter starting about halfway up the vehicle. The others are all Titan II -- the first and second stages are the same diameter all the way up to the payload fairing -- but the brightness and coloration of the plumes varies with lighting, film exposure, and film processing.

Comment: Highly recommend Ignition. It has been reprinted and is available on Amazon.

Comment: [How do rocket propellant combinations rank in terms of “brightness”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20601/12102) could use more answers; if you have anything to share there from *Ignition* that would be great, thanks!